# Windows 10 - hotkey to switch screen displays from only computer to duplicate

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

I need help with this hotkey to shift between screen displays from dual screens to pc screen only I need someone’s help please .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "shift".

Comment: @harrymc what I mean is switch from pc only to duplicate

Comment: I have an online exam I’m scared the proctor can detect my hdmi connected to the tv

Comment: Just disable that particular display during the exam.  Make this change before you start the exam if you are worried.